# Prove a spanning tree M is an MST for G with weights c > 0 if and only if M is an MST with weights c^x for x > 0

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree

> Prove -
> The spanning tree $M$ is a minimum spanning tree (MST) for $G$ with weights $c > 0$ if and only if $M$ is an MST for $G$ with weights $c^x$ for $x > 0$.

I am confused, how to prove this, as $c$ could be between $0$ and $1$, and then multiplying edge weights by $c$, will decrease weight. How can I prove the proposition?

Comment: I think the key property is that the relationship between edge weights, e.g. c1 < c2 is preserved after raising to positive powers. This carries through to sums of edge weights.

Comment: if the edge weight is c=0.5 raising 0.5^2 will decrease weight, but is the edge weight is c= 1.5, raising 1.5^2 will increase its weight. if the graph G has different weights, raising them to powers can change MST quite a lot.

Comment: Right, but when you are trying to find a minimum subset of edges, you care about the relationship between edges (rather than how an edge is weighted under different values of x; you should treat x as if it's a fixed positive value throughout your proof)